# How to insert digital signature in LibreOffice documents

Tags: security, libreoffice, signature

I was trying to  insert digital signature in LibreOffice writer documents. I went to file section then to digital signature. After that, I couldn't  insert my sign because the option was blank. How to do this?

[image]